# запрос к Hibernate со связью many to many

Tags: hibernate

Имею ситуация схожу с этой :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача:
Вывести не все поля User'ов, а только
iduser, firstnsme, languages,
где данные в поле languages сгруппировать в коллекцию объектов language.

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM User");
```

с этим запросом все получается, но выводятся лишние поля,

казалось бы можно поступить так:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT u.iduser , u.firstname, u.languages FROM User u");
```

но тут поле languages перестает группироваться в коллекцию. Поигравшись join'ами, criteria'ями не нашел пути группировки записей в коллекцию,
можно ли это решить на стороне hibernata или придется делать своими ручками?

Спасибо!

Comment: Нужен ли вам ORM, если отображением результата выборки в объекты вы всё равно не пользуетесь?

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать так:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("Select u.iduser as iduser, u.firstname as firstname, u.languages as languages " +
                    "FROM User u");
List<UserDto> userList = q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserDto.class)).list();
```

то вываливается то же самое исключение

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_2_0_, languagese2_.languageId as language1_0_, languagese2_.language as l' at line 1